# PHP merge arrays with same key to one custom array

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple result from mysql in array like this

Array1

```
Array
(
  [type] => Food
  [storage] => S5213
  [quantity1] => 1000
  [in1] => 10/09/2017
  [quantity2] => 1000
  [in2] => 10/09/2017
)
```

Array 2

```
Array
(
  [type] => Food
  [storage] => S4512
  [quantity1] => 990
  [in1] => 13/09/2017

)
```

Array 3

```
Array
(
  [type] => Drink
  [storage] => K4221
  [quantity1] => 12000
  [in1] => 12/09/2017
)
```

So, i would like to merge if the key such as "type" from different arrays are same and put it into custom array. At the same time, it maybe has quantity1, quantity2, quantity3 and in1,in2,in3 for different stocks quantity and date. Would like to merge it into "rack".

Expected result

```
Array
(
[Food] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [storage] => S5213
                [rack] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [quantity] => 1000
                                [in] => 10/09/2017
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [quantity] => 1000
                                [in] => 10/09/2017
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [storage] => S4512
                [rack] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [quantity] => 990
                                [in] => 13/09/2017
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[Drink] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [storage] => K4221
                [rack] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [quantity] => 12000
                                [in] => 12/09/2017
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Is it possible? tried using array_merge_recursive, but not output expected result.

Comment: please show what you tried and what it produced.

Comment: Also I note that you say the arrays are from mysql. If you have fields like quantity1, quantity2 etc in a table, then it looks like your first job is probably to properly normalise your table structure before you go any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what your SQL query returns, then it looks like your database is not normalised. More concretely, you should not have columns `quantity1`, `quantity2`, ...etc in a single table. The rule is, if you have more than one of some field, create a separate table. In this case that table should just have a foreign key, maybe a sequence number (1, 2, ...) and finally a single `quantity` column. Multiple quantities would be expressed as multiple rows in that additional table. The `in` field could be added to that, as it seems to follow the same rule.

Anyway, for the given situation, you could use this PHP function:

```
function addArray(&$main, $arr) {
    if (!is_array($main)) $main = []; // first time
    $main[$arr["type"]][] = [
        "storage" => $arr["storage"],
        "rack" => array_reduce(array_keys($arr), function ($acc, $key) use ($arr) {
            if (strpos($key, "quantity") === 0) {
                $acc[] = [
                    "quantity" => $arr[$key],
                    "in" => $arr[str_replace("quantity", "in", $key)]
                ];
            }
            return $acc;
        }, [])
    ];
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
$arr = [
  "type" => "Food",
  "storage" => "S5213",
  "quantity1" => 1000,
  "in1" => "10/09/2017",
  "quantity2" => 1000,
  "in2" => "10/09/2017"
];
addArray($main, $arr);

$arr = [
  "type" => "Food",
  "storage" => "S4512",
  "quantity1" => 990,
  "in1" => "13/09/2017"
];
addArray($main, $arr);

$arr = [
  "type" => "Drink",
  "storage" => "K4221",
  "quantity1" => 12000,
  "in1" => "12/09/2017"
];
addArray($main, $arr);
```

... etc. `$main` will have the desired structure.

Comment: Thank for suggestion. I gonna change the table now. Really appreciate on your help.